# Where can I get repair-part signal pins for a Nikon Nikkor AF-P lens?

Tags: nikon, diy, repair-parts

When attempting to replace a bayonet mount on my AF-P 70-300mm Nikkor lens, I inadvertently lost one of the 8 signal pins (CPU contact).Is there any source where I can just get a signal pin (or a set if I have to)?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if all the pins are actually connected inside the lens. This might not be the case - allowing you to just leave a gap where a pin is not connected anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Your only hope is someone selling salvaged used parts (or salvaging them from another lens yourself). Other than a few external cosmetic parts, such as rubber grips and battery doors, Nikon does not sell parts to anyone - even camera repair shops with great reputations. At least not in the U.S. and Canada.

Comment: And then there is [Nikon Shuttering Its Authorized Repair Program](https://petapixel.com/2019/12/10/nikon-is-shutting-down-its-authorized-repair-program-in-march-2020/)

Comment: @PeterM Thanks for the link. I was under the impression the deadline had already passed for third party repair shops that were once Nikon authorized repair centers.